# What's the best tool to close a circuit on purpose

Tags: tools

I have a PCB with some cheap SM switches (the ones with discs kept in place with adhesive tape or something like that).

I am using a screwdriver which is not reliable and I was thinking of something like a touch stylo covered with conductive ink. Is there something already on the market? I don't want to fix the switches, just be able to test the switch behavior.[image: Surface mount switch, broken]

Comment: Temporary short around switch? You can use tweezer, i guess

Answer (score 1):

Best solution so far: wrap a dead LED in aluminum foil and stick it on the top part of a pencil where the eraser is. So far better than the screwdriver and my hands tend to shake a bit.

[image: Poor man actuator]

Also I found this on Amazon which I will try later today: [image]

It works great!

[image]

Comment: Why not just wrap the pencil in foil?

Comment: Wrapping a LED with foil was a challenge. I am not ready to wrap an entire pencil yet. Plus I like the idea of a conductive tip... you are never too careful with those pesky capacitors.

Comment: Why the whole pencil? A simple cap for the eraser would do, and you can take it on and off. If after a few switches it won't stay, just use the tip of the finger to keep it in check.

Comment: well you asked me why the whole pencil and I explained why.
A cap for the eraser would be great if I could find one. At one point I was thinking of conductive paint but I don't how durable would be.

Comment: Also I am almost fifty years old and it's the first time I've heard about aluminum pencil caps... oh wow.

Comment: I think you misunderstood: what I meant is that, instead of adding an LED that you stick in the eraser and which want to wrap up in foil, don't use the extra LED and wrap up only the tip of the pencil in foil, which would result in that foil looking like a cap, that can be taken on and off. The LED, as it is in your picture, looks like having a cap of some sort. The reason I asked "why the whole pencil" was to draw attention on the fact that you'd be over-doing it, since you only need one end of that pencil to have a metallic contact. Also, choosing sarcasm over understanding is not very wise.

Comment: I was not being sarcastic. I didn't grow up in USA so I was genuinely surprised by pencil caps made of aluminum. Heck, I still am. By wrapping it around the LED I cause the foil to stay in place... but... I think I have found the best solution so far thanks to your pencil cap tip!

Comment: "*I didn't grow up in USA*" Neither have I, and it looks like I still haven't managed to explain what I meant, but if you found your solution, then it's purpose accomplished.

Comment: I understood your solution: a cap made of thin foil. I wanted something more permanent to dedicate to the purpose. Looking forward to try the cap from Amazon, the antiloss loop dealed the deal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115182/discussion-between-paperino-and-a-concerned-citizen).